# Testing the UI of web applications?

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, selenium, phantomjs, zombie.js

I am already using unit testing to ensure that all critical bits and pieces in my current web application works well. But what about testing the UI to ensure that the proper response occurs when an user hits a button for instance? - I mean, it's really going to make a mess if suddenly the `signup` button disappears or stops working, so I guess that it's common sense to perform this sort of UI testing as well.

From what I've read this far. [`Selenium`](http://seleniumhq.org/), [`PhantomJS`](http://www.phantomjs.org/) & [`Zombie`](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) *seems* to do what I want, but I know very little about them.

But what other alternatives are available and what should one consider before doing this type of unit testing?

Comment: Why not just start with one of these? They all work really, really well, or they wouldn't be the leaders.  I would suggest starting with a tutorial rather than a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `zombie.js` which was a pretty nice fit as we already had javascript knowledge inhouse.

Answer (score 3):

**Phantom and Zombie** are essentially the same thing. Both are **headless** browsers. Headless means that it behaves as a simple browser (opens the page, runs scripts, renders the content, handles cookies etc.) but no output is displayed to the user.

You define a test case using JavaScript

1. Open www.example.com page
2. Insert text "Bob" in "UserName" text field
3. Click on "Good morning" button
4. Check (assert) that the "output" field contains "Good morning Bob"

**Selenium** is a set of tools:

- **Selenium IDE** - a Firefox add-in that can record and play actions performed by you. It means that no scripting language knowledge is necessary to create and run test cases!
- Selenium **WebDriver** - a library that can "take control" over some supported browsers. It actually opens a selected browser (say Firefox) and performs the actions described in the test case code. (Note that Phantom headless browser is one of the browsers WebDriver can control).
- Some more like Grid for load testing, but don't know much about that

### To sum up

- If you want to test the front-end only, and are experienced with JavaScript - take Phantom or Zombie
- If you don't want to use JavaScript, choose Selenium IDE
- If you want to create more complicated tests (e.g. put some content into the database and then perform some operations in the browser) - use Selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of with Selenium as its got the stregth of powerful languages